# JMeter Dashboard - CPU Usage added to jtl file does not show percentage cpu

Tags: jmeter, perfmon

The dashboard that is generated via JMeter - When the PerfMon Metrics collector writes to the JTL file with CPU information, it presents response times (ms) in the Statistics section. However, I wanted to see the CPU Usage as a % (like you can see in the Chart display for PerfMon) presented in the dashboard Statistics section. How can I do that with the JMeter Dashboard? Thanks.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted, Thanks

Comment: Hi, what is meant by accepted an upvoted? Ive created a separate ticket  for it as it is an enhancement to the existing Dashboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot as of JMeter 4.0.

This would be an enhancement request to make and potentially contribute or sponsor.

To open such enhancement see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

Edit :

You opened:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62166

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem. The default result JTL file seems don't contains CPU information. I config the PerfMon filename in jmx file and it does works. I hope this can help you too.

```
<hashTree>
  <kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.PerfMonGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector" testname="jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector" enabled="true">
    <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
    <objProp>
      ......
    </objProp>

    #HERE config the perfmon infomation
    <stringProp name="filename">cpu.perfmon.base.jtl</stringProp>
    ......
  </kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector>
<hashTree/>
```